# how to expand mongodb shell validation errors?

Tags: mongodb

**Situation**

I am using MongoDB 5.0 community server locally. I am creating with the shell at the moment.

**Problem**

When I set up validation, and test that validation, I get an error. But the error is collapsed in an [object].

I have searched everywhere online but I cannot figure out how to get "verbose" error logging?

**Image of error**

This is what I see:

[image: This is what I see:]

My goal is to see the error details **inside the shell**.

Comment: Open a case at Mongo: https://jira.mongodb.org

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: If you assign a variable to the return value, can't you ""expand" it to reveal all the objects?

Comment: How can I achieve that in the shell @rickg12hs?

Comment: Something like `let result = ... whatever the command is`.

Comment: I am having this problem, how did you resolve this issue @Vinn